# What's correct: "Well done 'on' / 'for' your initiative"?

Tags: prepositions

When I want to encourage person for his initiative, what is the correct way to say it?

> 1) Well done **on** your initiative!"

or

> 2) Well done **for** your initiative!"

n.b. If you have better option how to phrase it, kindly let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either, but "on" is better. If you were to use "for", it would be borrowing from

> He earned a "Well Done!" from his boss for his initiative.

Most people won't notice a difference, however.